# Search and replace alphanumeric string having min length using regex while ignoring strings beginning with specific characters

Tags: regex, linux

I'm processing a bunch of log files in which I need to perform a search and replace operation. I'm working on a linux system.

This is my data, which I have saved as a .log file:

```
[12/21/16 10:59:58:378 GMT+05:30] 000022a8 Err     R profile.getId() PATADJO
[12/21/16 10:59:58:378 GMT+05:30] 000022a8 Err     R profile.getId() PTASDAS
[12/21/16 10:59:58:612 GMT+05:30] 00000104 Err     R profile.getId() MA2SD3ADA
[12/21/16 11:00:01:346 GMT+05:30] 000004a8 Err     R profile.getId() D04S4514
[12/21/16 11:00:10:841 GMT+05:30] 00000187 Err     R You have been registered successfully. Your ID is 1234567.
[12/21/16 11:00:01:346 GMT+05:30] 000004a8 Err     R profile.getId() BFDS343SDF
[12/21/16 11:00:10:841 GMT+05:30] 00000187 Err     R You have been registered successfully. Your ID is 1234567.
```

My goal is to search for alphanumeric strings like **BFDS343SDF**, only alphabetical strings like **PATADJO** and only numerical strings like **1234567** (all are ID's) and replace them with **Foo**. However, it should ignore the strings in the 2nd column **000004a8** (these are thread id's). You can assume that the thread id's always start with 00 and the ID's will never start with 0. Also, the ID's will have a minimum length of 6.

This is what I have now:

```
sed -i -- 's/^(?!00)[A-Z0-9]\{6,\}/foo/g' "sample.log"
```

However, when I run the command, it does nothing. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are ID's always at the end of the line?

Comment: no....not necessary

Comment: In your attempt, remove the carret (`^`) and replace it with word boundary (`\b`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt, remove the carret `^` (begining of line) and replace it with word boundary `\b`

using perl:

```
perl -api.back -e 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/foo/g' sample.log
```

The original file is save as sample.log.back

If you don't want to save original file:

```
perl -apie 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/foo/g' sample.log
```

Comment: It worked now...thanks a lot!!! But is there any way to not save the original file?

Comment: @GautamVenkatraman: Yes, there is. Remove `i.back` from the options, see my edit

Comment: Its printing the changed log file in the terminal....but its not making the change to the original file....I want the search and replace to happen in place, in the original file itself

Comment: @GautamVenkatraman: Sorry, my bad, remove the `.back` but keep the `-i` option.

Comment: Thanks...it worked....I just had to make a small change..perl -api -e 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/masked/g' sample.log